# error using AtomRSS class

Tags: fat-free-framework

im having a go at try to make use of AtomRSS.php (in lib) in a route of fatfree framework;inside the Class AtomRSS there is the static method read:

```
 static function read($url,$count=10,$tags='b|i|u|a') {
 $data=Net::http('GET '.$url);
 if (!$data)
return FALSE;
 $xml=simplexml_load_string(
 $data,'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA|LIBXML_ERR_FATAL
```

);

so in my route of index.php I thought this should be OK
    $f3->route('GET /feeds',
         function($f3)
      {

```
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
      $feed = "http://www.myjoyonline.com/pages/rss/site_edition.xml";
    $rss = new  \AtomRSS;
 $something =  $rss::read($feed);
```

});
but getting :HTTP Fatal error: Cannot make non static method Base::read() static in class AtomRSS (GET /feeds)

yes I should have read up more on oop!no joywith above but did notice in web.php (lib dir) there is function rss{} tried this:
    $f3->route('GET  /feeds',
    function($f3)
      {

```
$f3 = \Base::instance();
$url = "myjoyonline.com/pages/rss/site_edition.xml";
$rss =   new \Web;
$rss->rss($url); 
}
 );
```

maybe can use functions of newer classes?

Comment: actually that seems to work using :                                   $url = "http://www.myjoyonline.com/pages/rss/site_edition.xml";


    $rss =   new \Web;
    $result[0] = $rss->rss($url); 
    var_dump($result[0]); //it showed  got rss feed Ok and a load of text such as array(2) { ["source"]=> string(19) "Ghana News HomePage" ["feed"]=> array(10) so its just a case of array to string conversion to get neat result

Answer (score 0):

You're actually creating an object of the AtomRSS class which is not a static call. Try this instead:

```
$feed = "http://www.myjoyonline.com/pages/rss/site_edition.xml";
$rss = \AtomRSS::read($feed);
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working in a fashion link to where am to date here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f3-framework/BtvvbGuBmgU

like this: 
    $f3->route('GET  /feeds',
        function($f3)
          {
             $f3 = \Base::instance();
             $number = 2; 
            $result= Web::instance()->rss('http://www.myjoyonline.com/pages/rss/site_edition.xml',$number);
             for ($i= 0;$i< $number;$i++)
            {
          echo $result['feed'][$i]['title']."
";
          echo "". $result['feed'][$i] ['title']." "."
"; 
echo $result['feed'][$i] ['description']."
";
}

//var_dump($result);

}
);

output :
Patrons fear contracting infections at Korle Bu
Patrons fear contracting infections at Korle Bu
local news, ghana local news

Over 7,000 people at Mangu depend on two public toilet facilities
Over 7,000 people at Mangu depend on two public toilet facilities
local news, ghana local news